# Delphi10. Function to copy the character until this character ':'

Tags: string, delphi

Hello guys I want to do a function which stop and copy the string until the first character ':' is meet.
I have the following string '404:Bad Request' and my output is '404:' but i want just '404'.Here is my code:

```
function CutOff(const s: string; n: integer):string;
var
  i, k: integer;

begin
  k := 0;
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    k := Pos(s, ':', k+1);
    if k = 1 then Exit;
  end;
  Result := Copy(s, 1, k);
end;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `n: integer` parameter? You did not say anything about it.

Comment: If you are using Pos(), why are you also using the `for` loop is stepping through the string char-by-char?  Seems pointless to me, if you understand string processing.

Comment: Take a look at implementation of `ExtractName` method inside `TStrings` class: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Classes.TStrings.ExtractName. It does return the part before the delimiter. A similar function is also used in `JCL` - method `TJclWideStrings.ExtractName`: https://github.com/magicmonty/delphi-code-coverage/blob/master/3rdParty/JCL/jcl-2.3.1.4197/source/common/JclWideStrings.pas. But neither of those have a `n` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your function is intended to return the string up to the *nth* colon, contrary to what you say in your description: *... until the first character ':' is met.*

A problem with your code is however, that you have the arguments to the `Pos()` function the wrong way. After correcting that, to omit the colon you can simply subtract 1 from the length to copy:

```
function CutOff(const s: string; n: integer): string;
var
  i, k: integer;
begin
  k := 0;
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    k := Pos(':', s, k+1);
    if k = 1 then Exit;
  end;
  Result := Copy(s, 1, k-1); // note here k-1
end;
```

And to find the string up to the *first* colon you call it

```
Errorcode := CutOff('404:Bad request', 1);
```

Alternatively, if you never want the *nth* colon, only the first

```
function CutOff(const s: string): string;
var
  k: integer;
begin
  k := Pos(':', s);
  Result := Copy(s, 1, k-1);
end;
```